# how to update one column with trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, stored-procedures, trigger, update

i have 2 tables the first one is

**Table KEYS**

| game | keys |
| --- | --- |
| WOW | AAAAAAA-AAAAAAA-AAAAA |
| WOW | BBBBBBB-BBBBBBB-BBBBB |
| L4D2 | AAAAAAA-AAAAAAA-AAAAA |

**TABLE inventory**

| game | country | language | pieces |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WOW | USA | EN | 0 |
| L4D2 | USA | EN | 0 |

What i want to achieve is that column pieces on inventory gets updated by COUNT the game column of the keys table so at the end my inventory table should look like

| game | country | language | pieces |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WOW | USA | EN | 2 |
| L4D2 | USA | EN | 1 |

What i have tried

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 'inventario' AFTER INSERT ON `KEYS` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE inventory.pieces WITH SELECT COUNT(*) keys.game FROM keys WHERE keys.game = inventory.game
END $$;
```

i dont know if theres any other method to achieve this automatically after updating/inserting data on KEYS table

Comment: You should not store in the database anything that can be derived dynamically from what's already there, in your case the number of copies of a particular game.

Comment: thank you for answering so quick so you suggest i should update that column using php instead of a trigger or a stored procedure? @mustaccio

Comment: No, that is not at all what I suggest. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying that the row in `inventory` necessarily exists, the body of the Trigger is something like this:

```
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE inventory
        SET pieces = pieces + 1
        WHERE old.game = inventory.game
```

If you need to insert rows that have not yet been created:

```
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO inventory (
        ( game, country, language, pieces )
        VALUES
        ( OLD.game, 'USA', 'EN', 1 )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        SET pieces = pieces + 1
```

(Something would need to be done if it is not USA and EN.)

Answer (score 1):

i sincerly apologize i tried to search and search kind everywhere just after i posted i noticed on related questions this has been answered in the past https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135296/250535
sorry for this useless thread